# What does the universal property of Grassmannian mean?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, grassmannian

I was trying to figure out what is the universal property of Grassmannians, I saw a similar question [Universal property of the Grassmanian [closed]](https://mathoverflow.net/q/257653/97016).

And I have checked the references in the answer, and those references including Wiki didn't state the universal property formally. For example, Eisenbud & Harris' book shows the functorial of the Grassmannian $Gr_S(k,n)$ over the base scheme $S$. And three ways to construct the Grassmannian: locally covered by affine schemes, using Plucker equations embedded into projective space, as Hilbert scheme.

What does the universal property of Grassmannian really mean?

Comment: Given a compact manifold (this can be generalized) $M$ and rank $k$ vector bundle $E$ over $M$, there is a “classifying map” $f\colon M \to  G(k,N)$ (for suitable $N$) so that $E\cong f^*\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the tautological (sub)bundle on the Grassmannian. For non-compact $M$, we typically need $G(k,\infty)$.

Comment: Oh thank you, Professor, that seems to be what I was looking for (I came across it when constructing the period mappings in Hodge theory)

Comment: That comment is not completely correct and it is also not algebraic geometry. Rank k vector bundles are classified by BGL(k) and rank k subbundles of a trivial vector bundle of rank N are classified by the Grassmannian Gr(k,N), depending on your convention - some people prefer quotients.

Comment: Thank you Cranium Clamp , I will read Bott and Tu chapter IV about this subject later. A realted notes : https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/dafr/M392C-2012/Notes/lecture6.pdf theorem 6.19

Comment: @yili I haven't read that book but it is very good. A Grassmannian is a fine moduli space in algebraic geometry and I would recommend this viewpoint to you, which is the functor of points viewpoint. There is a detailed discussion in the book of Gortz and Wedhorn.

Comment: Thank you Cranium Clamp , Gortz and Wedhorn is a excellent reference that contains many materials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  [Gortz and Wedhorn section 8.4], the Grassmanian is a representable functor from $\text{Sch}^{\text{opp}} \to \text{Sets}$, such that

$$\text{Grass}_{d,n}(S) = \{\mathcal{U} \subset \mathcal{O}^n_S \mid \mathcal{O}^n_S/\mathcal{U}\text{ is locally free of rank } n-d\}$$

Which is represented by the smooth scheme Grassmannian denoted it also $X = \text{Grass}_{d,n} = G(d,n)$.

Now we have $$h_X(-) \cong \text{Grass}_{d,n}(-)$$ with $id\in h_X(X)$ sends to the tautological bundle $\gamma \in \text{Grass}_{d,n}(X)$ over $X$ via the isomorphism above.

Given any scheme $S$ with some subbundle $\mathcal{E}$ of trivial bundle then we have $\mathcal{E} \in  \text{Grass}_{d,n}(S)$, therefore exist some $f\in h_X(S) = \text{Hom}(S,G(d,n))$ such that $f^*\gamma = \mathcal{E}$ which coinside with what shown in the comment